# Can I determine if a value matches a type alias?

Tags: typescript, type-alias

In TypeScript, can I determine if a value is/matches a type alias?

Say I have this type:

```
export type Name = "Jane" | "John";
```

Then somewhere else I want to check if a certain piece of user input is of the `Name` type. Something like `if (input instanceOf Name)` won't work.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't check if a value matches a type alias. Types are erased at runtime, so any runtime code can't ever depend on them.

If you control the type alias I would recommend creating an array to hold the values, let TS infer the type for it, and derive the union from it. You can then check if a value is in the array:

```
const Name = ["Jane", "John"] as const
export type Name = typeof Name[number];

function isName(a: unknown): a is Name {
    return Name.indexOf(a as Name) != -1;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAcgQwLYFMYF4YG0BEApBMFHAGhnxAAswcBdGBCGUSKAKBQA8AHEAJ1hQAntzSJUGGMNEgAZvGQosYAK5IARij60A3GzayVYYFACW4GKYjiUACgQAuGEYDWYEAHcwASicJLTDYwAN5sMOEwfChQKnxgCqgAdKZgACZcAPKy9gyBit4wAISYALQAjHoAvvoANtEwEE7QfCkA5pIAsghQlIl8hKkgSLYFAHwwAAyJAKwwAPzkBEQ4ME44OHqm8rZWNrYQ3gWhEQ0wAPRnMEtoAD5XVGBslUA)

Answer (score 4):

The only way that I am aware so far is generating the type alias from a const array, then checking your name against this array.

```
const names = ["Jane", "John"] as const;
type Name = typeof names[number];

function isValidName(name: string): name is Name {
    return names.includes(<Name> name);
}
```

Usage:

```
const test: string = "John";
if (isValidName(test)) {
    console.log(`${test} is a name`);
}
else {
    console.log(`${test} is not a name`);
}
```

I still can't understand why typescript can't compile from something like

```
type Example = 'first' | 'second';
const exampleValues = [typeof Example] as const;
```

to

```
const exampleValues = ['first', 'second'];
```

the answer AFAIK is that "Types are erased at runtime", but compiling a type alias to a literal array does not require type information during runtime.

1. it imposes no overhead
2. preserves runtime behavior of javascript
3. and does not provide additional runtime functionality

this would allow for developers to validate a string at runtime by looking for a value inside the array.

If there is a way to accomplish this please let me know.
As I showed you can do the opposite, from an array to a type alias, but with type alias you can filter and combine types, and I am interested in converting from a type alias to an array **at compile time**.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript is structural typed language. It means that when you create a type, on the left you have a name, and on the right you have exact type representation in the runtime. There is no additional magic here as it would be in nominal type systems (classes and enums are exceptions).

It means that in order to check if something has this type we need to make explicit check or write a helper function to check it.

```
function isName(a: unknown): a is Name {
  return a === "Jane" || a === "John";
}
```

Maybe it looks cumbersome, but in general if you make union type, amount of options should be reasonable. If amount of options is really huge, probably data model is wrong, and we should rethink if we need such union.

Answer (score 0):

No, during runtime these information is not present and therefore cannot be used for such use cases.